# There is any efficient way to make search function to work?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have this function:

```
for (var i=0; i<tableLength ; i++)
    {
      if (getCallID == (sheetUserCalls.getRange('I' + i).getValue()) && (sheetUserCalls.getRange('G' + i).getValue() == userID))
      {
      sheet.getRange(cellToEdit).setValue("closed");
      sendText(userID ' + getCallID + ' ' + ' ' + 'was closed ');
      flag = 1;
      break;
    }
    }
    if (flag == 0)
      {
        sendText(userID , 'error: you canot close call of other person');    
      }
  }

  else 
  {
    sendText(userID , 'Bad request');  
  }
```

this code scan the whole "sheetUserCalls" sheet ('tableLength' is the amount of rows in this sheet) and
it should find line in this sheet that 2 parameters are identical ('getCallID ' and 'userID')  to what the user provided in his request, if it will find this line, it will document it in other sheet as 'closed' and will send to the user message that it has been closed.
if it wont find those matches, it will send to the user an error.
if no other condition will met, it will send 'Bad request' message

if there will be lots of lines, it will take long time to this function to run. there is any way to make it easier?

Comment: Yes, read once and write once, and manipulate/compare values within a JavaScript array. Read documentation on `Range#getValues()` and `Range#setValues()`.

Comment: thanks. can you give me an example?

Comment: only after you edit your question with the result of **applying** your own research on using `getValues` and `setValues` to your question. Note that an extremely large fraction of Stack Overflow's Apps Script + Google Spreadsheet questions use them.